# C++ function to Delphi XE7

Tags: c++, delphi

I have a C++ `function` :

```
 long CSP2_API csp2GetPacket(char szData[], long nBcrNr, long nMaxDataSz)
```

parameters are :

```
szData: buffer where the barcode data is stored in 
nBcrNr: the desired barcode’s index (which starts from 0L) 
nMaxDataSz: the maximum size of the szData buffer
```

My way of dealing with this is :

```
type
 TBarcode     = Array[0..99] of AnsiChar;


function csp2GetPacket(szBarData : TBarCode;
                      nBarcodeNumber: LongInt;
                      nMaxLength: LongInt): LongInt cdecl  {$IFDEF WIN32}stdcall {$ENDIF}; external 'CSP2.DLL';
```

and called using...

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
BarCode : TBarcode;
begin

  BarCode := #0;
  csp2GetPacket(BarCode,0,SizeOf(BarCode));

end;
```

The C++ documentation confirms it is using standard `ASCII` text for the *barcodes*.

Is there a better (more correct way) of calling the C++ `function`? or is this acceptable?

Comment: @RawN `AnsiChar` is always 1 byte. You are thinking of Delphi's `Char`, which is 2 bytes in D2009+. `char` in C++ is always 1 byte, so using `AnsiChar` in Delphi is correct, *especially* in D2009+.

Comment: C++ usually mangles names. What would be interesting to know is if this is declared as `extern "C"` or not. If not, you'll have to find out the real mangled name.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis CSP2 API is in actually C with stdcall calling conventions, not C++. Names in the import library are mangled accordingly (e.g. `_csp2GetPacket@12`). Names in the dll providing the API are not mangled (`csp2GetPacket`)

Comment: @Andrey: Ah, OK, then the names are not mangled. Good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
long CSP2_API csp2GetPacket(char szData[], long nBcrNr, long nMaxDataSz)
```

is translated like this:

```
function csp2GetPacket(szData: PAnsiChar; nBcrNr, nMaxDataSz: Longint): Longint; <calling-convention>;
```

Your translation is not correct. In C, one can degrade an array to a pointer, but in Delphi, you would really pass the entire array per value, so the translation is not binary compatible with the original.

I assume you have the calling convention right. If not, simply remove the `stdcall`.

I would simply use an `AnsiString` as parameter, cast to a `PAnsiChar`, more or less like:

```
var
  BarCode: AnsiString;
  L: Longint;
begin
  SetLength(L, 100);
  L := csp2GetPacket(PAnsiChar(BarCode), 0, Length(BarCode));
  // If csp2GetPacket returns the length, then: 
  SetLength(BarCode, L);
  // Otherwise, this will work too:
  BarCode := PAnsiChar(BarCode); // Copies up to and including terminating #0
```

I don't know the limits for the length of the buffer, so I assumed the same length as your code.

More info in my article on the subject of conversions: [Pitfalls of converting](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you know the barcode data will never exceed 100 bytes, then your approach is fine, though your function declaration should be more like this instead:

```
type
  TBarcode = Array[0..99] of AnsiChar;

function csp2GetPacket(szBarData: TBarCode; nBarcodeNumber: LongInt; nMaxLength: LongInt): LongInt; cdecl; external 'CSP2.DLL';
```

Or, if the function really does use `stdcall` on Windows instead of `cdecl`:

```
function csp2GetPacket(szBarData: TBarCode; nBarcodeNumber: LongInt; nMaxLength: LongInt): LongInt; stdcall; external 'CSP2.DLL';
```

Either way, a more correct translation of the function would be to declare the `szBarData` parameter as `PAnsiChar` instead:

```
function csp2GetPacket(szBarData: PAnsiChar; ...) ...
```

You can still pass a fixed array variable to a `PAnsiChar` parameter.

Comment: Is the first declaration correct. Does it really pass a pointer? It must make a copy at some point. I'd have expected the array to travel on the stack.